# How to change window color natively on iOS using Corona Enterprise?

Tags: ios, objective-c, lua, coronasdk, background-color

I'm new to Corona Enterprise and to Objective C but, I already got what I want working on XCode without Corona. Now, when I was trying to put it inside a Corona project, it didn't work well...

I reduced my code to the minimum where I only put the window color to Red. What's happening is that the window becomes Red but only for less then a second on the XCode simulator. After that, it becomes Black again...

Here's my code of AppDelegate:

```
showLoading( lua_State *L )
{
    void *platformContext = CoronaLuaGetContext( L ); // lua_touserdata( L, lua_upvalueindex( 1 ) );
    id<CoronaRuntime> runtime = (id<CoronaRuntime>)platformContext;
    runtime.appWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    // Return 0 since this Lua function does not return any values.
    return 0;
}

- (void)willLoadMain:(id<CoronaRuntime>)runtime
{
    lua_State *L = runtime.L;

    const luaL_Reg kFunctions[] =
    {
        "showLoading", showLoading,

        NULL, NULL
    };

    luaL_register( L, "window", kFunctions );
    lua_pop( L, 1 );
}
```

And on main.lua I only call:

```
window.showLoading()
```

What am I doing wrong? I just need to understand this in order to show the contents that I want inside the window. I tried with `runtime.appViewController.view.backgroundColor` but the screen still shows a Black color instead of Red...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found what was wrong while I was waiting for an answer. Here's the new code that is inside AppDelegate:

```
showLoading( lua_State *L )
{
    void *platformContext = CoronaLuaGetContext( L );
    id<CoronaRuntime> runtime = (id<CoronaRuntime>)platformContext;
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    if (!runtime.appViewController.view)
        runtime.appViewController.view=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:screenRect];
    runtime.appViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    // Return 0 since this Lua function does not return any values.
    return 0;
}
```

At the beginning, I thought that `runtime.appViewController.view` was already initialized. Now I see that it wasn't. But if I add any elements to `main.lua`, it is initialized and so, there's a need for a `if` to initialize it if it stills `nil`.